# Mobius strip as manifold and as a bundle over $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I am trying to construct the Mobius strip bundle onver $S^1$.

I am stuck in how to define charts for the Mobius bundle. Once I make this, the problem will easily be solved.

My attempt was:
$$M = [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}/\sim$$
where $(0,y) \sim (1,-y)$.

Then let $U_1 = (\frac{1}{8},\frac{7}{8})\times \mathbb{R}$
an open set and $\phi_1(x,y) = (x,y)$. This is one chart for $M$.

Another one is (?):

$$U_2 = [0,\frac{1}{4})\cup (\frac{3}{4},1]\times\mathbb{R}$$
$$\phi_2(x,y) = (x,y), ~ x \in [0,\frac{1}{4}),$$
$$\phi_2(x,y) = (x,-y), ~ x\in (\frac{3}{4},1]$$

Is this correct?

If it is, then I can define the trivialization as:

$$\psi_1(x,y) = (\exp{2\pi ix},y)$$
$$\psi_2(x,y) = (\exp{2\pi ix},y), x\in [0,\frac{1}{4})$$
$$\psi_2(x,y) = (\exp{2\pi ix},-y), x \in (\frac{3}{4},1].$$

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88137/real-line-bundle-smoothly-isomorphic-to-m%C3%B6bius-bundle

Comment: $\phi_2$ is not well-defined here, $\phi_2 (x,y)=(x,y)$ if $x\in [0,1/4) $ and $\phi_2 (x,y)=(x-1,-y)$ if $x\in (3/4,1]$ works fine.